# What is elegant solution for a PHP function with a lot of parameters?

Tags: php, arrays, parameters

I need to create a function that would insert user data into a "medical_records" table that has about 30 fields.

So the "classic" solution is writing something like:

```
function insert_medical_records($param1, $param2,..., $param30) {
    // code here
}
```

But of coarse, such code writing is prone to errors and not elegant at all.

I thought of better solution like creating an **array of parameters** and passing its values to the function, but I don't quite know a valid syntax for that.

Or maybe there is a better solution then this altogether?

Thank you!

Comment: Passing an array of values? Using the splat operator? get_func_vars()? Using data objects?

Comment: There are many ways to do it and I am not sure of the most elegant but here is an idea: Pass an object? Each record would be an attribute of said object. Ooo I like that create a Person Class with a constructor that takes in the required minimum fields and set all the others...sounds fun. Funner in c# xD..i miss those days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since php has a soft type control, you can just give your function one input parameter. That parameter will be an array or an object.

In case of an array:

```
function insert_medical_records($input_array) {
    // Here you can use $input_array['param1'], $input_array['param2'],
}
```

Before calling the function, you need to populate the array, something like:

```
$input_array['param1'] = "your param 1 value";
$input_array['param2'] = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);

insert_medical_records($input_array);
```

I would also suggest you to check the content of the input variable of the function:

```
function insert_medical_records($input_array) {
  if (!isset($input_array['param1'])) {
     // manage your error
     return;
  }
  // Everything is ok. Do your stuff here...
}
```

Instead of [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), you should also consider using [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) or [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). This it's up to your specific situation.

The solution using Object instead of Array is really similar. You define attributes such as `$input_object->param1`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class MedicalRecords {
    /* code here */
}

function insert_medical_records(MedicalRecords $mr) {
    /* more code here */
}
```

and now you can add logic to do thing like validation on the records to the object itself and better seperate your code's concerns along more logical lines.